# AngularJS promises returning object rather than resolved value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

```
function times() {
  var deferred = $q.defer();

  var data = $http.get('https://bus.data.je/latest');

  data.success(function(_data) {
    deferred.resolve(_data);
  });

  data.error(function(error) {
    deferred.reject(error);
  });

  return {
    all: function() {
      return deferred.promise;
    },

    timetable: function(type) {
      _data = deferred.promise;
      return _data.filter(function (el) {
        el = el[0];
        return el.MonitoredVehicleJourney.DirectionRef == type;
      });
    }
  }
}
```

When either return functions are queried, it returns an object containing promise functions (`finally`, `catch` and `then`), rather than the resolved value. How do I fix this?

Comment: [Avoid the Deferred antipattern!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-deferred-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it) Hint: all references to `deferred.promise` could simply be replaced by `data`.

Comment: You cannot synchronously get the resolution value of a promise back. Promises are still asynchronous, all you can do is to derive another promise from them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't. What you do is expose your own API as promise-based:

```
function times() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    var data = $http.get('https://bus.data.je/latest');

    data.success(function(_data) {
        deferred.resolve(_data);
    });

    data.error(function(error) {
        deferred.reject(error);
    });

    return {
        all: function() {
            return deferred.promise;
        },

        timetable: function(type) {
            return deferred.promise.then(function (data) {
                return data.filter(function (el) {
                    el = el[0];
                    return el.MonitoredVehicleJourney.DirectionRef == type;
                });
            });
        }
    }
}
```

and then use it like so:

```
times.timetable().then(function (timetables) { /* work with the timetables here */ });
```

Because, like the comments pointed out, you can't make promises synchronous after the fact.